# How do I increase website page width specifically on Mr. Parker Shopify theme

Tags: shopify

I am trying to make my website pages full width but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with my specific shopify theme, Mr. Parker. I think I have to make changes to the stylesheet.css.liquid, but I am struggling to figure it out. Is there a way to make my pages full width in the Mr. Parker theme?
I am a newbie and trying to do this on my own with very little background in this area. Any help is appreciated. 
Amy

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried (show your code!) and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!  Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

**Hard way:**

go learn css , html , js stuff to the end.

**Easy way:**

i don't know these stuff you said but i know pure CSS and HTML, easy way is to inspect element the page by chrome and check the biggest part of the page, like the `<body>` tag, then check the style tab and see what is the most top CSS file it's affecting from. change the file and you are ok!

Attention: Front-end developing is a huge field, elements on the page may affect from JavaScript then it could be so much hard for you to change things.
btw its very hard to edit responsive websites for the newbies, cause the elements may affect from multiple lines and codes and by many actions.